# decimal point and zero are removed after adding two equal floating numbers in php

Tags: php, floating-point

I am trying to solve a problem on HackerRank and its not making any sense.

```
<?php
  $d = 4.0;
  $f = 4.0;
  $sum = $d + $f;
  echo $sum;
 ?>
```

I need an output of 8.0 but its giving output of 8. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Float values with decimal part equal to zero gets printed without the decimal part. If you need to force certain numbers of decimal places, use [`number_format()`](http://php.net/number_format).

In your case: `echo number_format($sum, 1);`

Comment: it needs to be generic. I am solving a problem online and they can test with any value they want. any number of digits after decimal point.

Comment: I probably don't get it - if anyone tests 4.0 + 4.0, both 8 and 8.0 are valid answers, aren't they?

Comment: Yes they are. Its a problem on HackerRank.  Their testing mechanism won't just accept it. It only accepts 8.0

Comment: I tested it by concatenating a decimal point and then 0 with it. It worked. But I didn't submit my code because they are going to run different test cases off course!